# Embeded Rules Engine as a service

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, rules, rule-engine

I have been searching around an open source rules engine that supports .net for a while now. The aim of it is to allow end users to edit their own rules via a customised Web client UI, in order to control their house's energy consumption ( e.g. turn something ON/OFF.. ).

It seems that Drools is one of the best on the list of rules engines. However, its maintaned version supports Java, but for the .NET platform, it has been abandoned pretty much since 2007. I couldn't find any helpful article or tutorial in which Drools .NET was integrated whithin a .NET 4.5 application.

So for now my conclusion is that open source BRE don't support .NET well. Therefore, I started some trials with WWF using its Rule SET and also WebRule ( its free version). Both has some limitations when it comes to exposing rule editing to the end user via customised UI. That's why I am planning on exposing the BRE as a service and then creating a UI that communicates with the BRE via Web API.

Is that even possible? Do you guys think that this strategy can lead me to achieve my object, Or should I explore others paths?

Comment: You want to create your own rules UI and you think that your UI will serve you better than those BREs that you mentioned?

Comment: Im not looking for a substitute to those BRE, Im just asking for a way to make rules editing accessible for end users via a customised UI ( drag and drop in a puzzle or something like that ). But as far as I know none of these BRE gives the possibility to manage their UI, that's why my question was about accessing the BRE functionnalities via Web services.. ( forgive me if my question is a bit trivial, I am still new to the rules engine world :) )

Answer (score 0):

did you try wso2 brs?

It uses drools, and expose as web service by rule server. Seems it works just like what you want.

Comment: I actually implented my solution using OpenRules, its architecture is based on SOA, so exposing it as a service was exactly what I needed.